# How to disable mouse in gvim without breaking selection?

Tags: vim, gvim

If I select text from command-line vim and copy it to the clipboard, it includes line numbers (from `set relativenumber`). Gvim is smart about selection and does not copy the line numbers. However, if I do `set mouse=""` in gvim, it makes it behave like command-line vim (line numbers are copied).

I don't want to enable the mouse in gvim because I don't like the cursor moving when I click. Is there any way to disable the mouse in gvim without making copying to the clipboard grab line numbers?

Comment: Your terminal emulator might let you do block selection, that could be a workaround.

Comment: Wow. I never realized that works. It looks like ctrl-dragging does block selection.

Comment: excellent, just wanted to know how to switch the mouse off - the only thing I've found annoying switching from vim to gvim - I like being able to use it to scroll but accidentally moving the cursor when clicking is annoying

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use Vim as it's supposed to be used: with the keyboard.

**Visual selection:**

- `v` character-wise
- `V` line-wise
- See `:help visual-mode`

**Copying:**

- `y` places selected text in the default register
- `"*y` places selected text in the `*` register (the GUI clipboard when available)
- See `:help registers`, `:help yank`

**Pasting:**

- `p` puts the content of the default register after the cursor
- `"*p` puts the content of the `*` register after the cursor
- See `:help put`

You won't paste line numbers if you use Vim correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is basically that you copy the line numbers? Why don't you just add a mapping to toggle your line numbers?

Something like this for example:

```
map <Leader>nn :set relativenumber!<CR>
```

Then you wouldn't need to copy the line numbers in the first place...

Comment: Right now I have to toggle paste mode before I paste, and this would mean I would have to toggle "copy" mode, too. It's better than nothing, but it would be ideal if there weren't a manual step.